# External List & Picking pictures from a Picture Library

Tags: external-content-type, external-list, image

I have an external data source (BDC) based on which I created an external list. The (external) entity provides a field which can store / contain the link to an image.

Now there is an Image Library which contains the images that could be added to the respective field on the entity.

My question is: How can I provide some kind of an image picker in the EditForm of the external list, to allow the user to easily choose an image from the Image Library?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With External Lists you do not have the luxury of creating custom Asset Picker. You could probably consider building yourself some ECMAScript based Web Part.

Comment: Hm ok. Is this still true for Sharepoint 2013?

Comment: Not sure, haven't tried, but I would expect so.